# Laravel Xdebug with SPA (Vue.js, React.js ..)

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

How to debug Laravel project with Xdebug when using Single Page Application for front end, like Vue.js, React.js etc? Tutorials on this seems to be outdated.

I have setup Xdebug on my windows machine with Laragon nginx, PHP 8.1.2 and also installed related xdebug.dll for my PHP from Xdebug official website. But Xdebug does not connect to my PhpStorm IDE. I also installed Xdebug helper extension on Chrome which sends cookie header correctly for PhpStorm.

```
[12344] Log opened at 2022-04-20 19:55:22.015861
[12344] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[12344] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[12344] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[12344] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9003.
[12344] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not connect to client host discovered through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003. :-|
[5520] Log opened at 2022-04-20 19:55:32.343684
[5520] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[5520] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[5520] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[5520] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9003.
[5520] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header). :-)
[5520] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///D:/Projects/iq/iq-integrate/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.2" protocol_version="1.0" appid="5520" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="3.1.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you try to debug SPA or not. Each call to backend (php) should run xdebug. Did you configure xdebug log? Did you try to stop on first line (PhpStorm setting)?.

Comment: it does not start debugging on PhpStorm

Comment: Please add here your xdebug config from php.ini.

Comment: To find out what happens in the Xdebug site, please let make Xdebug create a log file for you. You can do that by setting `xdebug.log=c:\temp\xdebug.log` (make sure to pick a path that exists, and is writable by your web server), and `xdebug.log_level=10`. For each request, this log will indicate if a trigger was present, and if/how it tried to connect to PhpStorm.

Comment: updated with xdebug log file contents

Comment: `[5520] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header). :-)
[5520] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///D:/Projects/iq/iq-integrate/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.2" …`
Indicates that it did connect. Is that all in the log?

Comment: Yes, then in PhpStorm it does not start

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help someone
i used extension requestly  to send xdebug key and
it helped me. xdebug starts working
Other extension like xdebug-helpers are not sending xdebug key.
my front app on vuejs spa